# Adding date labels on the x-axis in a 3D plot (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

This is my first 3D plot ever and I´m unsure how to add date labels to my x-axis.

```
%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, np.transpose(Z), color='red')
ax.set_ylim([0, 30]) #TTM
ax.set_xlim([0, len(x_TradeDate)]) #TradeDates
ax.set_xlabel('TradeDate')
ax.set_ylabel('Time to maturity')
ax.set_zlabel('Spot rate')

plt.show()
```

I have tried using `ax.xaxis_date`, `ax.xaxis.set_ticks` and `ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels`, however it doesn’t seem to work or I simply do not know how to use the commands in the correct way.

My plot looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CymNF.png).
What I want is to have the x-axis (TradeDate) labelled with dates. Right now the x-axis is simply, [x-axis values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtSLz.png). I have 103 dates in [X_TradeDates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5LNv.png) and I want to use these dates as labels. How do I do that? I also have the dates in string format in a list, [date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5WVr.png), if it easier to use those.

I hope I have provided sufficient information otherwise please do not hesitate to ask.